# Extension degree must be power of prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, prime-numbers, extension-field, separable-extension

Problem statement: If $K/F$ is a finite separable extension, and for any field extension $M/F$, $[M:F]$ is divisible by a fixed  prime $p$, show that $[K:F]$ is a power of $p$.

Primitive element theorem tells us $K = F[\alpha]$. I am thinking about picking some element and use tower lemma, but I seem to miss pieces?

Comment: I assume that $p\mid [M:F]$ is only supposed to hold for extensions $M\ne F$.

Comment: @leoli1 By the way, is field $F$ necessarily perfect?

Comment: No, consider a non-perfect field $k$ of characteristic $p$ and let $F$ be the separable closure of $k$. Then $F$ is not perfect and all algebraic extensions of $F$ are purely inseparable, in particular have degree divisible by $p$ (if they are not trivial).

Comment: @leoli1 Is it possible to prove that in the non-perfect case, we must have $char = p$ (without using separable closure)?

Comment: A non-perfect field always has prime characteristic and as such a field admits a purely inseparable extensions this prime has to be the same as $p$ (by the divisibility assumption).

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|128.0500).  This post misses the mark.  Try to read it, or parts of it; surely you'll find a couple suggestions that you can take with you to edit and improve this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint:** By replacing $K$ with the normal hull over $F$ we may assume that $K$ is finite and Galois over $F$. Then consider the fixed field of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$.

Comment: Please review [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|138.3752).  Please understand that we hope answerers assist users to improve their posts, and *not answer* the post until and unless they do improve it.  Thanks.