# Field must be perfect or characteristic p

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, characteristics

Problem statement: Given field $F$, if for any field extension $M/F$, $[M:F]$ is divisible by a fixed  prime $p$, show that $F$ is either perfect or have characteristic $p$.

Previously in this question [Extension degree must be power of prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4239738/extension-degree-must-be-power-of-prime), I see that $[K:F]$ is a power of $p$ through Galois closure. I also know that irreducible but inseparable polynomials must have certain form. But is it possible to continue from here without the notion of separable closure?

Comment: Any field of characteristic 0 is perfect.

Comment: @MartinSkilleter Huh? That does not seem to be a hint?

Comment: Consider your field $F$. It either has characteristic 0 or characteristic $p$. Use my above comment to conclude.

Comment: @MartinSkilleter No. It is not that simple.You may want to read the question again..Why does it have to be $p$?

Comment: My apologies, you're right. I missed that the two primes were meant to be the same.

Comment: Well alright, let's suppose that $F$ doesn't have characteristic $p$ and show that it must be perfect. If $char(F)=0$ then as I said before, we're done, so we can suppose that $char(F) = q$ for some prime $q \neq p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $F$ is not perfect; then we have $q:=\operatorname{char}F>0$, and there exists an element $\alpha\in F$ that is not a $q$-th power. Now the polynomial $x^q-\alpha$ is [irreducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351431/proving-xp-a-is-irreducible-iff-a-is-not-a-p-th-power-of-an-element) in $F$, so the ring $E:=F[x]\big/\langle x^q-\alpha\rangle$ is a field extension of $F$ of degree $q$. On the other hand, by the problem hypotheses, $[E:F]$ must also be divisible by $p$, so this forces $q=p$, as desired.

Comment: Why does there exists an $\alpha$ that is not a $q$th-power?

Comment: @SmoothKen oh, apologies, that's the definition of a perfect field that I use :) (namely, a field is perfect iff either its characteristic is $0$ or its characteristic is $p>0$ and every element of it is a $p$-th power.) ... what characterization are you familiar with?

Comment: perfect if and only if char 0 or Frobenius is surjective, which means imperfect and char > 0 implies Frobenius not surjective.....I see your magic.....

Comment: precisely! :) ${}{}$